# $\mathbb{Z}$-homology plane and compact support cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

If an affine hyper-surface $X$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$ has the property that $H^i_c(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ for $i =4 $ and zero otherwise. Can I say it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-homology plane?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is smooth? Then this follows by Poincaré duality: $H_j(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_c^{4-j}(X;\mathbb{Z})$.  So $X$ has the same integral homology as a plane, which is presumably what's meant by $\mathbb{Z}$-homology plane.

Comment: No!! $X$ may have singularities.